# Can an HOA make up new rules other than explicitly stated in CC&Rs?

Tags: property, texas

In Texas, in an area governed by an HOA, the CC&Rs regarding lawns state that grass must be kept cut in a neat and attractive manner.

Can an HOA then tell a homeowner they must cut down mature trees because the grass doesn't grow under them because of the density of the trees?

The trees are not damaging the house, cement, nor are they diseased. They are healthy trees that do not let enough light come through that grass can grow under them.

If the homeowner makes an attempt to try to fix it by planting shade tolerant grass can the HOA require the homeowner cut the trees down at the homeowners expense so that grass can grow?

Comment: Do you have a clause covering disputes or non-compliance?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt the CC&Rs do not appear to mandate the creation of conditions for grass to grow, so where is the noncompliance?

Comment: @phoog I infer someone thinks the grass is not neat or attractive which does seem to be in the CC&Rs. I wonder if that person has a particular basis for choosing how it should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, they seem to be stating that the absense of enough grass under the trees means the grass is not neat and attractive. But the CC&Rs state that the grass must be "cut" in a neat and attractive way. The word cut specifically, not grown, kept, cultivated, etc. And they are suggesting that mature non-diseased trees must be cut down to get the grass to grow.

Comment: You confirmed my assumption, but neglected adding the interesting part. In general an HOA has as much power as you sign over to it. Did you sign something that said the committee chair can direct how to fix problems or disputes go to the HOA committee?

Comment: This isn't me - as then it would be a specific legal post. But from the CC&Rs I don't see where there is anything signed over that allows the HOA to direct how to get grass to grow. My thoughts would be to buy some sod and lay it down, take a picture and there is some grass. Not sure if that is necessary tho.